# Not able to run TestNG test

Tags: java, testng, ui-automation, testng-eclipse

I am getting the below error on running `TestNG` test. Kindly suggest what could be wrong.

Note: I have installed `TestNG` v 708 from Eclipse IDE. My project is not a Maven Project so I have not added any dependency, it's a normal Java project.

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.8.0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at org.testng.log4testng.Logger.lambda$getLogger$0(Logger.java:30)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708)
    at org.testng.log4testng.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:30)
    at org.testng.TestNG.<clinit>(TestNG.java:113)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNGFactory7_8.createRemoteTestNG(RemoteTestNGFactory7_8.java:16)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:67)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 6 more
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Did you see the error message? It cannot find  `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory`. At this point you can either install that manually (a web search should find it) and hope that this is the only dependency TestNG has, and if not, resolve any other dependencies manually as well. Or, and I'd recommend that, switch to Maven or Gradle and let the tool handle the dependencies for you.